# Double satellite flare on iridium 6

Tags: atmosphere

Last night here in Southern California, I was watching the flare of the Iridium 6, I use the Sputnik app to alert me. I was amazed when I saw not one but two bright lights tracking simultaneously.. One in front of the other. I have never seen this before. Can you explain what I saw? Was it a reflection of two parts of the satellite? It was amazing!

Comment: Related - http://space.stackexchange.com/q/14101/4660 . Do you have the data from Sputnik for the flare? It didn't alert that it would be a double flare?