# What did I see? Multiple "satellite" flares

Tags: satellite-flare

I came across this page this evening after witnessing around 15 what looked to be satellite flares in the same region of sky within about ten minutes. All of the objects flared multiple times with a frequency of around 3 to 5 seconds. Each would cover around 15 or maybe 20deg of sky, almost directly above my head. Appearing from the east, heading west. Most were on very similar trajectories. At least once I had two objects in view at the same time, appearing almost as a pair of aeroplanes in flight together. But these were 100% not aeroplanes. They were almost certainly in orbit, catching the sun. Each was in view for something like twenty seconds and without exception they went from being not visible to really quite bright straight away and all originated in the same small area. Most followed pretty much the same path but a few deviated a little more and I am quite sure that they did not all travel in parallel lines ie while they originated from the same spot, some had different headings to others. 50% of them were on very similar trajectories. The first one I saw, I was pretty sure was a meteorite coming through on a pretty straight up and down trajectory ie, it wasn't streaking across the sky but instead brightening while moving slowly indicating it was heading vaguely in my direction. Just to give a sense of things. It took about five seconds for me work out that I was seeing something flaring. Then it just got weirder after that. :)

I am no expert but I have spent what must add up to a numer of days staring at the night sky in my lifetime and it's right up in the top 3 most unusual things I've seen. I must have seen a thousand satellites but I've never seen one flare like this and certainly not 15 of them! Speed wise I would describe them as like fast satellites..

I'd very much like some assistance figuring out what I may have seen. A recently destroyed satellite?? That's my best bet. But like I say, I'm just an interested layman. :)

**Details:** Date 30th September time approximately 20:00-20:30 (British Summer Time; UTC+01), location SE England, post code ("zip code") area GU31

---

Related:

- [What is a "Double Iridium Flare" and how close can the two satellites be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14101/12102)

Comment: These days, the answer is always Starlink. I do not have the ability to look it up, but heavens-above.com will list passes. I believe there was a launch at so.e time on Sep 29.

Answer (score 5):

These days whenever one sees a train of satellites it is almost always Starlink. Starlink is a constellation of internet satellites from SpaceX (you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink)). Whenever SpaceX launches a falcon 9 with Starlink satellites, they usually deploy multiple satellites at once ranging from anywhere between 20 - 60+ satellites. This is why you saw many of them in a line. SpaceX most recent launch was on [September 29th](https://www.spacex.com/launches/) so it is definitely possible that what you saw was indeed Starlink. In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgysWWwESfU) it shows some Starlink satellites flying over a house, so you might want to check that out and see if that was anything similar to what you saw.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer because I need to catch a train - I'll flesh it out later today.

- script: https://pastebin.com/3NgNLN1C
- input: https://www.space-track.org/auth/login (free but registration required)
- with help from https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/gp.php?GROUP=starlink&FORMAT=tle
- and: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Starlink_and_Starshield_launches

[image]