# Any idea what's in the SE sky from Denver around 12:40PM EDT?

Tags: iss

[image]There's something that's visible in the SE (roughly) from Denver now ~12:40PM. It seems to be tracking north. I tried taking a photo but my camera doesn't have the resolution. I'm really curious. I understand the ISS can be visible during the day.

[image]

Comment: Could you please [edit] to include more detailed information? For example, how long does the object appear over the horizon, at what angle, how fast is it moving, from which direction, how bright does it appear to be, does it change in brightness, color, and so on. What you describe could be anything, but it wasn't the ISS since it was South of Madagascar at 12:40 p.m. MDT today (2014/09/15). Also, the ISS can't be seen during the midday, only from dusk till dawn. See [Can I see the ISS from the surface with the naked eye?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/4034/49) for explanation.

Comment: It's been visible since about 12:30pm, when I noticed it near the sun. It's tiny, yet bright enough to be see clearly. Now it is due east at about 45 degrees. I'd guess it has moved across about 1/5th of the sky in last 40 minutes. I did capture it on my camera, however it's just a bright dot in the sky.

Comment: Could be a (weather) balloon or a blimp catching reflection off the Sun. It's not a satellite and it's moving too slow to be an airplane. We also pollute the skies with rather strange airborne things, this is a huge, partially deflated "Donald Duck" helium balloon I shot once overflying my place at the distance of about 2-3 miles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Y7K.gif Now, it wasn't a bright sunny day as you can probably see from the stack of shots, but if it was, I suspect it would appear pretty bright and a rather odd addition to the skies above. BTW that's a telephoto zoom, plus cropped.

Comment: And this https://i.stack.imgur.com/188lg.jpg is about as bright of sky during which you can still see the ISS with a naked eye. Shot is a 1 minute exposure made early in the morning with the station towards South-West when the station was reflecting particularly lots of sunlight with its solar panels due to low beta angle at which it was orbiting at that time of the year. It should also give you a fair impression of its speed and brightness when crossing the skies (though brightness varies and depends on the Sun-Station-Observer phase angle, it's about as bright as it gets on this shot).

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the analysis. I did use binoculars and still it appeared roundish, so a weather balloon makes sense. I suppose I'd need a telescope to see better, which I don't have anyway.

Comment: *"Them's the Aliens, Jeb! They's comin' for you!"*

Answer (score 9):

[Flightradar24](http://www.flightradar24.com/HBAL374/455c412) says that a couple of Google's [Project Loon](http://www.google.com/loon/) high-altitude balloons have been meandering around Denver airspace for the past day or so.  It's quite possible that what you've been seeing was one of them.